# What should I do on logging out when Alamofire request is authenticated?

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire` request for all web calls. Initially when I login, I authenticate the request with some USERNAME and PASSWORD. Say USERNAME is JOHN and PASSWORD is 1234.

Say I logout immediately and I login with some other credential, say USERNAME is PETER and PASSWORD is 4321. App logs in again with the old credential JOHN and 1234 only. The new value is not at all applied.

On logging out, what should I do to remove the previous session when logging out?

Added the snippet

```
func login(userName: String!, password:String!, completion: (error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        print(userName)  // Prints PETER for second attempt
        Alamofire.request(
            .GET,
            Management.LOGIN_URL)
            .authenticate(user: userName , password: password)
            .responseJSON { response in
                // But gives JOHN's data for second attempt
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    print(JSON)
                    self.setCookies(response)
                    self.setUserData(JSON as! NSDictionary)
                    completion(error: error)  
                    }

                case .Failure(let error):
                    completion(error: error)
                }
        }
    }

func logout() {
        Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.resetWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
            print("Resetted")
        }
    }

private func setCookies(response: Alamofire.Response<AnyObject, NSError>) {
        if let
            headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String],
            URL = response.request?.URL
        {
            let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headerFields, forURL: URL)
            Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, forURL: response.response!.URL!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u show ur tried code

Comment: where you called this `login` method

Comment: In my LoginViewController. The snippet I added here is my APIManager

Comment: can u show that method `Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.login`

Comment: That is a button action in LoginViewController. I pass textfield values as userName and password

Comment: can you send your project to my mail id, I will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication in Authorization header helped me.

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/password", headers: headers)
         .responseJSON { response in
             debugPrint(response)
         }
```